# Back Button not working inside Webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-html, dart-null-safety

I wrote the code by wrapping willpopScope so that I can get previous page of webview but it is not working thus it is closing the entire webView page .

Here is the full code :

```
class Resources extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResourcesState createState() => _ResourcesState();
}

class _ResourcesState extends State<Resources> {

  late WebViewController _controller;

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  Future<bool> pop(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
            child: WillPopScope(
              onWillPop:()=> pop(context),
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(),
                body: WebView(
                  gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                  initialUrl: 'https://www.edhitch.com/login.html',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controllerCompleter.future.then((value) => _controller = value);
                    _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);

                    },
                ),

              ),
          ),
            ),
        );
  }
}
```

I have used will scope which takes bool function pop kindly help me out with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code hope it helps to you:

Create Future function using async and it will return true

```
Future<bool> onWillPopFunction() async {
    return true;
}
```

and call your onWillPopFunction, function on onWillPop event

```
WillPopScope(
    child:  Scaffold(), 
    onWillPop: onWillPopFunction,
)
```

you also add alert box for warning like (exit your app or not?)

Or try below code

```
 IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
    ),
```

Comment: Didn't help I want to go back to the previous webpage instead of that it is closing the whole web page.

Comment: @HarshKumarYadav See my updated answer for IconButtton

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the controller when the WebView is created and pop for the controller, not the app context:

```
onWillPop: (){
    _controller.goBack();
},
```

(updated, since "Controller.complete()" does not exist anymore)

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
    _controller = webViewController;
},
```