# Flutter Webview Back Button Controller

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I have a Flutter project with Bottom Navigation Bar. There are 2 tabs in the Bottom Navigation Bar. One page is webview and the other is flutter page. I add these two pages to my home page with include. I want to manage the navigation in the webview when the back button is pressed while the inside webview is on the page.

Home Page Code:

```
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return (showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Sure?'),
            content:
                new Text('???'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text('No'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: new Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )) ??
        false;
  }      
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Widget> pageList = [
          MainHomePage(
            text: widget.text,
          ),
          WatchPage()
        ];
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
          child: Scaffold(
            //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Container(
              child: pageList[_activePage],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
              animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
              color: Color(0xff1f5269),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _activePage = index;
                });
              },
              items: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.tv,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

WebView Page:

```
  WebViewController controller;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  Future<void> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    print("onwillpop");
    if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
      controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(true);
    } else {
      //exit(0);
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _onWillPop(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 10,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            color: Color(0xff1f5269),
          ),
        ),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: widget.text,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController c) {
              _controller.future.then((value) => controller = value);
              _controller.complete(c);
            },
            onProgress: (int progress) {
              //print("Webview is loading(progress: $progress&)");
            },
            onPageStarted: (String url) {
              if (url == "https://app.testt.com/Login/Cikis") {
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new LoginPage()));
              }
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              if (url == "https://app.testt.com/Login" ) {
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new LoginPage()));
              }
            },
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68716137/13997210) hope it help you

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I want to control webview. Thank you for your help.